# Upload Image / Display and Save it to database in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to upload and display an image to the database. I have a model to add EmployeeFirstName, LastName,... and employee image. When I post form all data posted except the image file.

Here is my code.

Model:

```
namespace EmployeeTask.Models
{
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   public partial class Employee
   {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> HiringDate { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
   }
}
```

View:

```
<div id="dialogEmployeeEditor">
<div>
    <h2>Add/Edit Employee</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:EmployeeEditor_Save();">Save</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="Container">
    <form id="frmEmployeeEditor">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="EmployeeEditor_FirstName" value="@emp.FirstName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
           .........

            <tr>
                <td>Upload Image</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="imageFile" id="image" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="employeeId" value="@emp.Id" />
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function EmployeeEditor_Save() {
    $.post("/Employees/SaveEmployee", $("#frmEmployeeEditor").serialize(), function (e) {

        $("#EmployeesGridContainer").replaceWith($(e));
        $("#PopUpContaine").dialog("close");
    }, "json");
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveEmployee(int employeeId)
{

        SaveEmployeeDate(employeeId,Request.Form);
        return PartialView("_EmployeesGrid");
}

public void SaveEmployeeDate(int employeeId, NameValueCollection Data)
{
        Employee emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == employeeId);

        if (emp == null)
        {
            emp = db.Employees.Create();
            db.Employees.Add(emp);
        }

        emp.FirstName = Data["FirstName"];
        emp.MiddleName = Data["MiddleName"];
        emp.LastName = Data["LastName"];
        emp.HiringDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Data["HiringDate"]);
        emp.Department = Data["Department"];

        HttpPostedFileBase image = Request.Files["imageFile"];

        if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[image.ContentLength];
            image.InputStream.Read(imageBytes, 0, image.ContentLength);
            emp.Image = imageBytes;
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15662252/3383479

Answer (score 5):

In order to get `HttpPostedFileBase` types to post correctly, you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form header.  You could just write it manually as `<form id="frmEmployeeEditor" enctype="multipart/form-data">`, but I would recommend using MVC's form helpers to do the same thing like this (in your cshtml view):

```
@using (Http.BeginForm("Employee", "SaveEmployee", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}) 
{
     // Your form goes here
    <input type="file" name="imageFile" id="image" />
}
```

Then, in your controller, you can simply add a parameter to your post action that will get the file automatically, like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveEmployee(int employeeId, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
{
    // Controller code here
}
```

`imageFile` should no longer be null and you can save it to disk, or get the bytes to save to the database.