# How to Upload 2 Image Files into MVC C# 5 database in its respective Byte[] array property?

Tags: database, image, asp.net-mvc-5, image-uploading

```
public class Opportunity
{
    [Key]
    public int OpportunityId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Graphics Image is required")]
    public byte[] Graphics { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Faculty Picture")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Faculty Image is required")]
    public byte[] FacultyPicture { get; set; }
 }
```

Controller:

```
 namespace Kaust.Views.Opportunities
 {
  public class OpportunitiesController : Controller
  {
    private KaustContext db = new KaustContext();
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "OpportunityId,Graphics,FacultyPicturen")] Opportunity opportunity)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Opportunities.Add(opportunity);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

View:

Create index:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Opportunity</h4>
    <hr />
            @Html.Images(m => m.Graphics, "Graphics", "id")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Graphics, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Opportunity</h4>
    <hr />
            @Html.Images(m => m.FacultyPicture, "Graphics", "id")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FacultyPicture, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

And @Html.Images is a customhelper:

```
  public static IHtmlString Images<TModel,TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string name, string id){
        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("input");
        tb.Attributes.Add("ex", expression.ToString());
        tb.Attributes.Add("name", name);
        tb.Attributes.Add("id", id);
        tb.Attributes.Add("type", "file");
        tb.Attributes.Add("accept", "Image/*");
        return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

It creates this output:

```
<input accept="Image/*" ex="m => m.Graphics" id="id" name="Graphics" type="file">
```

When I click the submit button:

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

I have seend several methods to change the image file to Byte[] but I just don't know how to do it before the submit button or because it doesn't get into the "httppost method".

I have tried this solutions. but... I still get the error.

[How to upload/display images using ASP.net MVC4 with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662252/how-to-upload-display-images-using-asp-net-mvc4-with-entity-framework)

http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/uploading_and_returning_files

The question is how can I save this files into the databases in after clicking the submit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties in your model need to be `HttpPostedFileBase` (not `byte[]`) for binding to a file input in the view. Since your also wanting to store the filein the data base, you will need a separate view model and data model

```cs
// View model (Note ID property not required)
public class OpportunityVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Image is required")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Graphics { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Faculty Picture")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase  FacultyPicture { get; set; }
}
```

And in the POST method

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([OpportunityVM model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }
  // Initialize data model
  Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity();
  using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(model.Graphics.InputStream))
  {
    opportunity.Graphics = reader.ReadBytes(model.Graphics.ContentLength);
  }
  if (model.FacultyPicture != null && modelFacultyPicture.ContentLength > 0)
  {
    // ditto for FacultyPicture
  }
  db.Opportunities.Add(opportunity);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Note that you also need to include the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` attribute in the form tag

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Opportunities", FormMethod.Post, new {  enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`

Side note: Your generating invalid html. Both file inputs in your model have `id="id"` (duplicate `id` attributes)

There is no need to pass the `name` and `id` to the helper (and in fact a minor typo passing the `name` means binding will fail). Instead use the `ModelMetadata` to generate the correct attributes. In addition, `ex` is not a valid attribute and its not clear what you are trying to achieve with `tb.Attributes.Add("ex", expression.ToString());` but it should be removed.

```cs
public static IHtmlString Images<TModel,TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    string id = HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName(name);

    TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("input");
    // tb.Attributes.Add("ex", expression.ToString());
    tb.MergeAttribute("name", name);
    tb.MergeAttribute("id", id);
    tb.MergeAttribute("type", "file");
    tb.MergeAttribute("accept", "Image/*");
    return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answe Stephen! now I have another error while i'm trying to scafolding the model:
HttpPostedFileBase: EntityType 'HttpPostedFileBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType
HttpPostedFileBases: EntityType 'HttpPostedFileBases' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType
what should I do with this?

Comment: You cant have `HttpPostedFileBases` in a data model. You need a view model. Then in the post method, you initialize an instance of the data modelm set its properties based on the view model and save it.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more detail to show what you need to do to store the files in the database (assumes that only the `Graphics` file is required)

Comment: Both are required I haven't noticed that in the model, I dont have a cklur how to set that modelview but ill try it

Comment: OK, Just add the `[Required]` attribute to the second one and you don't need the `if (model.FacultyPicture..` line. And all your need to change in the view is to use `@model OpportunityVM` instead of `@model Opportunity`

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen... One last Question... I dont have any upload attribute in the code, where did you got that ? in the Readbytes(upload.Contentlength)

Comment: Oops - that should have been `model.Graphics.ContentLength`

Comment: Got it, I did the ViewModel as you suggested and I could have the files. Now I have same problem, when I select the 2 files and try to send the model, it doesn't bring the Images in the OportunityVM, how can I correct this?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what your mean by _it doesn't bring the Images in the OportunityVM_. You code is for selecting and uploading 2 images to database. Do you also want another view that displays those images?

Comment: In the OpportunityVM (ModelView), I have the 2 properties HttpPostedFileBase with the "name" and "id"  for Graphics and FacultyPicture. When I hit the Submit button, the Post action "Create(OpportunityVM model), doesn't have the Images loaded in this model so It doesn't work uploading the files

Comment: Just noticed you have not included `enctype= multipart/form-data` in the form tag :) - see update

Comment: Thanks once again it worked
Im working now in the opposite (get image from the byte[] Array

Comment: Best guess is that you want something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560830/convert-byte-array-to-image-and-display-in-razor-view)